# Every irreducible Polynomial is primitive or irreducible constant

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R$ be an [UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain). Is it true that an irreducible polynomial $f \in R[T]$ is either:

- primitive
- $f \in R$ and irreducible in $R$
  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $f \notin R$ and $f$ is not primitive. Then $f$ can be factored into its content and primitive polynomial, so $f$ is not irreducible.